# Functional Programming: Equivalence and Evaluation to a Value

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm reading some notes on SML and am a bit confused by one of the author's remarks.  Let `e ==> v` indicate evaluation to a value and `e ~ e'`
indicate that `e` is extensionally equivalent to `e'`

The author writes:

> If `e ~ e'` (both of type `t`) and there is an SML value `v` of type `t` s.t. `e ~ v`, then there is an SML value `v'` (again of type `t`), s.t. `e' ==> v'` and `v ~ v'`.
>
> Make sure you notice that (and understand why we did *not* say here that if `e ~ e'` and `e ~ v` then `e' ==> v`.

Why not?

Comment: Given how `==>` is defined, what could you say about `fn x => 0` vs. `fn x => (0 + 0)`?

Comment: @gallais I'd say they always evaluate to the same value, so they're extensionally equivalent

Comment: Does SML reduce under lambda abstractions? If I'm not mistaken these two functions are *values* already and they don't reduce anymore. But they are indeed equivalent because they're extensionally equal.

Answer (score 2):

Because that would mean that both reduce to the same *syntactic* value. But extensional equality is not the same as syntactic equality. It means, roughly, that there is no way *for a program* to tell the values apart.

Note in particular that function expressions are values themselves. But different function values with different bodies may still be extensionally equal, because they compute the same result when applied to the same argument. Trivial example:

```
fun x => x
```

and

```
fun x => let y = x in y
```

are two values that are syntactically different but extensionally equal.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with `e` and `e'` being values `v` and `v'` already, then the second statement would say

> If `v ~ v`' and `v ~ v`, then `v' ==> v`

which can be simplified as

> If `v ~ v'`, then `v' ==> v`

which is the exact opposite of extensionality, since you can have e.g.

```
v = fn x => x + 0
v' = fn x => x
```

which are not the same value, but are extensionally equal.